# Global definition in python classes

Tags: python, class, object-oriented-analysis

I'm writing a class to analyze some data. One of my functions creates a dict to store the results:

```
def get_top_hits(self):

    global output_dict
    output_dict = {} 

    with open(self.all_employees)as file: 

        employees_data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
        result = [row for row in employees_data]
        result.pop(0)
        for row in result:
            name = row[0]
            job = row[1]
            number = row[2]
            output_dict.setdefault(name, set()).add(job)

    return output_dict
```

However, when I try to access output_dict with another function inside the class definition, Python tells me output_dict is not defined.
I know the functions work properly, but I can't figure out how to make them work in my class definition.

Comment: Why is output_dict declared global? What is hits_data? (Did you mean employees_data?)

Comment: I need to iterate over output_dict later. I'm really new to Python so I thought I could use this to update the items.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this a method of the class, or just a function? You are returning output_dict, so it should not be global. If you want it available everywhere in the class, add it to self, like @Chris Curvey suggests.

Comment: It is a method of the class. Should I put self.output_dict = {} inside: def __init__(self, summary, all_hits, hits_cut, miss_cut, strong_hits_cut)? Or inside the method that uses it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh, if this is a function within a class, don't use a global, make it an attribute of the class!

```
self.output_dict = {}
```